# in pdfml how to set radio button to true

Tags: xml, pdf, pdf-generation

In PDFML how do I set a radiobutton to be selected, or set a radiobuttongroup to have a value of one of them?

I have choice1, choice2,choice3 and they are all part of radGrp.

I have added this to show text but not sure how to set a radiobutton.

```
<mapping type="stamp" align="left" >
    <pdfField fieldname="textfield">
        <para>
            <p>
                <t>text value</t>
            </p>
        </para>
    </pdfField>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Is your question about pd4ml or about IText?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I've Googled and found [Language Reference Manual: PDFml A PDF Manipulation Language](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/classes/2011/w4115-fall/lrms/PDFml.pdf) where it says: *PDFml files compile internally (using logic written in O’Caml) into Java code, which is then run
on the native Java Virtual Machine (using a library called iTextPDF).* There are three e-mail addresses mentioned in that document. I suggest that f1wade contacts those people as nobody at iText knows about PDFML.

Comment: Or, you know, somebody edits the question and removes the itext tag? #icanhazreputation

Comment: @BrunoLowagie there is PDFml (your link) and there is pd4ml (http://pd4ml.com/), 2 totally different things, and my guess is that it is a question about the latter. But we can't be sure until the OP replies.

Comment: 1 more approve vote needed to have your edit accepted, @AmedeeVanGasse If the question is indeed about pd4ml, than we have yet another case of someone who uses the iText tag under a false pretext in the hope that an iText engineer will look at his question. Tsssk... Has iText become a brand name like Pampers. Has it become a word that people use for a PDF library no matter which library they are using?

Comment: I sense a disturbance in the Force... as if someone is writing a blog post for the iText blog, about exactly this topic. :)

Comment: its about PDF manipulation language, but the code I have inherited is also using itext library directly.
and for your blog, when i think of pdf i think of itext for creation and jpedel (idr solutions) for display and data manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only answer I can figure out, is to extend and write it yourself.